# Convert a SharePoint 2010 application server to a WFE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, configuration

I have an application server in a SharePoint 2010 enterprise farm that currently has only search services running on it. I want to convert it to a WFE to help with the current traffic/nintex workflow load.

I'm assuming the main steps will be to start the web application and workflow timer service for the application server in central administration.

After this is done will everything needed be populated into IIS or are there additional steps I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure couple of things.

- Start the **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application ,Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service**
- Add the Server in the Loadbalancer
- Update the IIS bindings
- Update the SSL cert on this server if you are using the SSL
- make the changes on that server related to Web.config( if any) or other OOTB customization if deployed into the farm.
- Make sure you Logs drive has enough space on this server if not alian with WFE